# Order results from query by custom score defined in aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a bunch of objects like this:

```
{
  "id": "12dfb835-6a0c-4047-ab51-d4e34116478e"
  "foo": "bar"
}

{
  "id": "3297b9d2-e05c-4874-91e4-c5b11e8e38c2"
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

I also have the below query. It basically groups documents by `id`, then calculates a score based on a script.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "userID": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "my-awesome-score": {
          "scripted_metric": {
            "init_script": "state.scores = []",
            "map_script": "state.scores.add(42)",
            "combine_script": "double score = 0; for (s in state.scores) { score += s } return score",
            "reduce_script": "double score = 0; for (a in states) { score += a } return score"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This returns results like this:

```
 "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "12dfb835-6a0c-4047-ab51-d4e34116478e",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "my-awesome-score" : {
            "value" : 42.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "3297b9d2-e05c-4874-91e4-c5b11e8e38c2",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "my-awesome-score" : {
            "value" : 42.0
          }
        }
        ]
```

However, in the `hits` of my query result, all my documents have the default `_score` of 1. How do I get Elastic to use `my-awesome-score` as the value for `_score` for my hits, and sort by that metric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregations API is separated from the hits/search API so aggregation result **cannot** be used to influence scores or sorts returned along with the hits.

You could apply [script-based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html#_script_based_sorting) but the main takeaway here is that the score is confined to a single hit and unlike a scripted metric aggregation mentioned in your snippet, it'll never have access to other docs' attributes. In other words, your script can generate a score just for the doc it's currently passing through -- independently of the other docs.

Comment: Thanks Joe, guess I'm going to do some magic in C# to sort my results afterwards then.

Comment: All good, good luck with the wizardry 